# Encryption and decryption

Tags: java

I am trying to creat a loop so this program will continue until the user asked to Exit but I know I need to use the do-while loop but for some reason its not working how can I be able to fix this. I want the user to press like E(Exit) and the program will stop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
/**

 */
public class ENCRY
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        try{
            do{
                Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Please select an Option");
                System.out.println("Encrypt the Sentence");
                int File =input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("--------------------");
                System.out.print("Enter the sentence:");
                String s = input.next();

                KeyGenerator keygenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES");
                SecretKey myDesKey = keygenerator.generateKey();
                Cipher desCipher;
                desCipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
                desCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);
                byte[] text = s.getBytes();
                System.out.println("" + new String(text));


                byte[] textEncrypted = desCipher.doFinal(text);
                System.out.println("sentence Encryted : " + textEncrypted);
                desCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, myDesKey);

                byte[] textDecrypted = desCipher.doFinal(textEncrypted);
                System.out.println("sentence Decryted : " +  new String(textDecrypted));



while()



        }catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException S)
        {
            S.printStackTrace();
        }catch(NoSuchPaddingException S)
        {
            S.printStackTrace();
        }catch(InvalidKeyException S)
        {
            S.printStackTrace();
        }catch(IllegalBlockSizeException S)
        {
            S.printStackTrace();
        }catch(BadPaddingException S)
        {
            S.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't written a do/while loop anywhere in your code. Also, the tags you used on your question were completely irrelevant - please only choose tags related to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is something like the following

```
do{ 
 //code you want to run
}while(!stop);
```

Where  stop is changed to true upon a key event (eg. The user pressing the "e" key) or possibly a JButton.

Comment: When I do that and compile it its said cannot find symbol- variable stop

Comment: Did you declare a boolean type value named stop at the beginning of your programme and set it to false?

Comment: Thanks I fixed that but what good Exit java code is good so I can ask the user to press E and close the program.

Comment: My best idea right now would to add another System.out.println() at the end of your programme that tells the user what key to hit to close the programme.

Comment: System.out.println("Have a nice day."); 
                System.exit(5);

Comment: This will close it but does not give me the option to ask the user what to press to close the program.

Comment: Perhaps you could use a key listener in conjunction with the boolean variable so if a key is pressed and stop is true then it closes the programme.

Comment: System.out.println("\r" + "\r" + "E. Exit");
                System.out.println("Have a nice day."); 
                System.exit(5);

Comment: This will display the Exit sign and close the program